# Are $L^\infty(\Bbb R)$ and $L^2(\Bbb R)$ homeomorphic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

It's easy to see that, for $1\le p,q< \infty$ the spaces $L^p(\Bbb R)$ and $L^q(\Bbb R)$ of $p$-th and $q$-th power integrable functions on the real line are homeomorphic as topological spaces. In fact, the map $f(x)\mapsto sgn(f(x))|f(x)|^{q/p}$ provides an explicit homeomorphism $L^p(\Bbb R) \to L^q(\Bbb R)$.

However this argument cannot be applied to the case where $p$ or $q$ equals infinity.
Thus, I'm asking whether there is a homeomorphism from $L^\infty(\Bbb R)$ to any (and hence every) $L^p(\Bbb R)$ with $p<\infty$.

Comment: Isn't $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ separable and $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ nonseparable?

Comment: A more interesting question would be: are $L^2({\bf R})$ and $C_0({\bf R})$ homeomorphic?

Comment: Any two separable infinite dimensional Frechet spaces are homeomorphic.  This is due to M. I. Kadec.

Comment: Maybe check your explicit homeomorphism $L^p(\Bbb R) \to L^q(\Bbb R)$ more carefully.

Comment: Jerry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: The $q/p$ should be $p/q$ if you want it to take $L^p$ to $L^q$.

Comment: @PaulMcKenney I like the use of the rhetorical question...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Paul is right. $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is separable. (The rational simple functions ought to be one example of something ctbl. and dense.)

However, $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ isn't separable. By Jones' Lemma, if $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ were separable then any closed discrete (i.e., nonclustering) set must be of size less than continuum. But the characteristic functions $\chi_{[0,x]}$, $x\in[0,\infty)$, are pairwise of distance 1 from eachother.

Comment: This was already pointed out in comments

Comment: And I was clearly elaborating on that comment.

Comment: We need answers, since comments are likely to go away in the future.

Comment: We need answers, since questions without answers constantly float back to the first page.

Comment: Jones' Lemma seems like overkill here.  Since the continuum-many functions $\chi_{[0,x]}$ are pairwise distance 1 in $L^\infty$, the continuum-many open balls $B(\chi_{[0,x]}, 1/2)$ are pairwise disjoint.  Any dense set must contain points in every one of these balls, so a dense set in $L^\infty$ must have size at least continuum.